# text not floating around image and background color not working

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4, frontend

New to using boostrap, trying to get text to float around the two images (one floating to the right with text on the left, and the other image floating to the left with text on the right)
There's also an issue with my background color, it's not covering the whole page
suggestions and help would be very much appreciated, thanks! :-)

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}

.logo {
  height:135px;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar {
  background: black;
  font-family: 'Degular', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-link,
.navbar-brand {
  color:#eae2d8; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-link {
  margin-right: 1em !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color:  #f2cfb9;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-top: 35px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Degular', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f2cfb9;    
}

.Kayla {
  width: 400px; 
  height: auto; 
  border-radius: 30px; 
  float: right;
}

.Coffee {
  width: 400px; 
  height: auto; 
  border-radius: 30px; 
  float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 600px)  { 
  .Kayla {
    float: none;
  }

  .Coffee {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="Branding/NavLogo.png"> <img class="logo" src="Branding/NavLogo.png"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#navbar">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#container-fluid">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<h2 style="font-family: 'Buena-Park-JF', serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-size: 50px; padding-top: 40px;"> Great Music </h2>
<img class="Kayla" src="imgs/30207a8c-04ee-49f8-8cc8-feee6b7b3157.JPG">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
<h3 style="font-family: 'Buena-Park-JF', serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-size: 50px; padding-top: 40px;"> Great Coffee </h2>
<img class="Coffee" src="Branding/coffeepackagingmockup.png">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
```

Comment: one thing to say straight away as I recognize it: `@media (max-width: 600px) {` should be: `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {`

Comment: @tacoshy, thanks! What about the problem with the background color?

Comment: In the snippet it displays black as defined. What is wrong with it, how is it supposed to look?